# SQL Server access via SSH tunnel: SSL Provider error certificate verify failed

Tags: sql-server, ssh

I have set up an SSH tunnel to an SQL Server instance running on AWS RDS. I was using Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server driver. My trouble was that I could not reliably login to the database. Sometimes I get login timeouts.

I upgraded the driver to Microsoft ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server and now I can't connect at all and I immediately get this error.

```
File "/Users/me/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mssql/base.py", line 353, in get_new_connection
    conn = Database.connect(connstr, **args)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: ('08001', '[08001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]SSL Provider: [error:0A000086:SSL routines::certificate verify failed:unable to get local issuer certificate] (-1) (SQLDriverConnect)')
```

I feel like maybe I have never been connecting to the DB properly but only since the new driver do I get a proper error.

I use the app Core Tunnel to do the SSH command to start the tunnel on my local Mac.  The command it uses is:

```
ssh -N -i "/Users/me/Library/Group Containers/E2343S7W4U.io.coressh.ssh/.ssh/privatekey/mysshkey" 
    -L localhost:1433:my-database.rds.amazonaws.com:1433 
    -o ServerAliveInterval=15 -o ExitOnForwardFailure=yes 
    -o ServerAliveCountMax=3 -p 22 eric@12.34.56.78
```

where `12.34.56.78` is the public IP of the EC2 instance that has access to the database.

After the tunnel is running, I point my Django app to `localhost:1433` to try to access the database and that is when the error occurs. Like I said, this setup worked with the old driver but wasn't reliable, and the login timeout error it would sometimes give was on the same line of `mssql/base.py`.

Comment: Does SQL Server have a proper SSL certificate set up?

Comment: @Charlieface I'm not sure if it has an SSL cert. Ideally, I'd like to bypass the SSL cert verification.

Comment: It always has one, by default it will be a self-signed one. Newer drivers enforce encryption, for good reason, so ideally you should get a proper certificate. Barring that, use `'TrustServerCertificate': False,` in the `OPTIONS` of the connection string

Comment: ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server added a breaking change that, by default, requires a trusted X.509 certificate to be installed on the target SQL Server. (Thanks, Microsoft, that covers maybe 2% of the installed userbase.) Ref: [ODBC Driver 18.0 for SQL Server Released](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server-blog/odbc-driver-18-0-for-sql-server-released/ba-p/3169228), which gives you options on how to handle the new scenario.

Comment: Do SQL server machine and client (python) match ODBC Driver version?
I tried downgrading to ODBC 17 and everything worked out